# Talagrand's functional and Dudley's sum (Vershynin 8.5.2)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Looking at Exercise 8.5.2 in Vershynin's book High-Dimensional Probability, page 207

Consider the set $T\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $T=\left\{\frac{e_k}{\sqrt{1+\log n}}\,,\,k=1,\ldots,n\right\}$. If $T_k\subset T$ with $|T_k|\le2^{2^k}$, then:

(a) Show that the $\gamma_2$-functional of $T$ (with respect to the Euclidean metric) is bounded, i.e. $$\gamma_2(T,d)=\inf_{T_k}\sup_{t\in T}\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{k/2}d(t,T_k)\le C.
$$
(b) Check that Dudley's sum is bounded, i.e.
$$\inf_{T_k}\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{k/2}\sup_{t\in T}d(t,T_k)\rightarrow\infty$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

=================

I believe the natural approach would be to set $T_k$ to be the first $2^{2^k}$ elements of $T$, in which case $d(t,T_k)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\log n}}$ for each $k<\log\log n$. But then aren't both quantities at most $2\sqrt{\log n}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\log n}}<C$?

Why does Dudley's sum diverge?

Comment: The elements of the set are $e_k / \sqrt{1 + \log k}$ not $e_k / \sqrt{1+ \log n}$

Comment: Ah I see 8.5.2 has $1+\log n$ but 8.1.12 has $1+\log k$. Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess there are edition discrepancies. In [this version](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~atml192/wiki.files/vershynin-%20High-Dimensional%20Probability.pdf), both are $\log k$.